# Why Nullable<​DateTime> can be assigned to a paramter which only can be implict converted from DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable, amazon-dynamodb

There is no implicit conversion from Nullable<​DateTime> to DynamoDB​Entry. 
But I have code like this. It works well.

```
class DocumentData {
    private readonly Document doc;

    protected void SetValue(string key, DateTime? dateTime)
    {
        DateTime? old = GetDateTime(key);
        if (old != dateTime)
            doc[key] = dateTime;
    }
}
```

---

In fact, I tested some other code. I think it's nothing to do with DynamoDB.

```
class TestDateTIme
{           
    public static void Test() { 
        DateTime? a = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Convert(a);
    }
    public static void Convert(MyClass m){
        return;
    }
}

class MyClass 
{
    public static implicit operator MyClass(DateTime date)
    {
         return new MyClass ();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the `Document` type? Is it part of DynamoDB? Can we see its documentation or source code? It seems to have an indexer that takes one parameter of type `string`. Is the type of that indexer really `DynamoDBEntry`? Can we see?

Comment: Document is a class in DynamoDB. THe indexer is DynamoDBEntry. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK/Amazon.DynamoDB/DocumentModel/Document.cs#L71).

Comment: There *does* exist a conversion `operator` from the non-nullable `DateTime` to the DynamoDB entry, or not?

Comment: Yes. There is an implicit conversion from the non-nullable DateTime to the DynamoDB entry. But how can a Nullable<DateTime> be implicit converted to DateTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. What you dexcribe is this:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public static implicit operator MyClass(DateTime date)
    {
         return new MyClass ();
    }
}
```

That's an implicit user-defined conversion from a non-nullable value type (here `DateTime`) to the class type, a reference type.

Then a conversion `DateTime`→`MyClass` "induces" a conversion `DateTime?`→`MyClass` as it seems.

With the above example, this compiles:

```
DateTime? nullableDateTime = XXX;
MyClass myClass = nullableDateTime;  // implicit conversion from nullable!
```

I tried to read carefully the part of the C# Language Specification beginning with:

> **User-defined implicit conversions**
>
> A user-defined implicit conversion from type `S` to type `T` is processed as follows:
>   [...]

Here the source `S` is `DateTime?`, and the target `T` is `MyClass`. With the notation of the spec, `S0` and `Sx` become `DateTime` and the conversion you wrote is "selected".

When `nullableDateTime` has a value, it is pretty clear that this value is unwrapped, then fed to the user-definede conversion of yours. It *seems* to be in agreement with the spec.

When `nullableDateTime` does not have a value (is null), it looks like the resulting `myClass` becomes a `null` of that type, that is a `null` reference of the class type. This is based on experimenting. **I am not sure where in the spec this behavior, with `null` from struct to class, is described.**

Conclusion: The behavior you asked about, is probably a consequence of the way the specification is written, but I am not sure where it says that `null` shall go to `null` without actually invoking your conversion method.